# Creating temporary folders

Tags: .net, io

I am working on a program that needs to create a multiple temporary folders for the application. These will not be seen by the user. The app is written in VB.net. I can think of a few ways to do it such as incremental folder name or random numbered folder names, but I was wondering, how other people solve this problem?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Update:** Added File.Exists check per comment (2012-Jun-19)

Here's what I've used in VB.NET.   Essentially the same as presented, except I usually didn't want to create the folder immediately.

The advantage to use [GetRandomFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx) is that it doesn't create a file, so you don't have to clean up if your using the name for something other than a file.  Like using it for folder name.

```
Private Function GetTempFolder() As String
    Dim folder As String = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath, Path.GetRandomFileName)
    Do While Directory.Exists(folder) or File.Exists(folder)
        folder = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath, Path.GetRandomFileName)
    Loop

    Return folder
End Function
```

**Random** Filename Example:

C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Temp\u3z5e0co.tvq

---

Here's a variation using a Guid to get the temp folder name.

```
Private Function GetTempFolderGuid() As String
    Dim folder As String = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath, Guid.NewGuid.ToString)
    Do While Directory.Exists(folder) or File.Exists(folder)
        folder = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath, Guid.NewGuid.ToString)
    Loop

    Return folder
End Function
```

**guid** Example:

C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Temp\2dbc6db7-2d45-4b75-b27f-0bd492c60496

Comment: Shouldn't your loop condition include `File.Exists` in addition to `Directory.Exists`? There could be an existing temp _file_ in `Path.GetTempPath`, and that would prevent creation of a directory.

Comment: You're right.  I'll update the answer to include a File.Exists() check

Comment: You should **create** the folder within the function -- for the same reason that GetTempFileName creates the file: to make sure there's zero chance someone else does.

Comment: Remember to do `Imports System.IO`

Answer (score 19):

You have to use `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()`

> Creates a uniquely named, zero-byte temporary file on disk and returns the full path of that file.

You can use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName())` to get only the temp folder information, and create your folders in there

They are created in the windows temp folder and that's consider a best practice

Comment: Do **NOT** do this. Calling `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName` on `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName` is the worst replacement for `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath`, as it creates a file that gets left behind.

Answer (score 8):

Just to clarify:

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
```

returns just the folder path to the temp folder.

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
```

returns the fully qualified file name (including the path) so this:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName())
```

is redundant.

Comment: GetTempPath and GetTempFileName are 2 completely different methods.
GetTempPath just returns the location of the system's temp folder, while GetTempFileName creates a temporary zero-length file and returns the full path of that file.

Answer (score 8):

There's a possible race condition when:

- creating a temp file with `GetTempFileName()`, deleting it, and making a folder with the same name, or
- using `GetRandomFileName()` or `Guid.NewGuid.ToString` to name a folder and creating the folder later

With `GetTempFileName()` after the delete occurs, another application could successfully create a temp file with the same name. The `CreateDirectory()` would then fail.

Similarly, between calling `GetRandomFileName()` and creating the directory another process could create a file or directory with the same name, again resulting in `CreateDirectory()` failing.

For most applications it's OK for a temp directory to fail due to a race condition. It's extremely rare after all. For them, these races can often be ignored.

In the Unix shell scripting world, creating temp files and directories in a safe race-free way is a big deal. Many machines have multiple (hostile) users -- think shared web host -- and many scripts and applications need to safely create temp files and directories in the shared /tmp directory. See [Safely Creating Temporary Files in Shell Scripts](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/content/view/115462/81/) for a discussion on how to safely create temp directories from shell scripts.

Answer (score 6):

As @JonathanWright [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217198/196844), race conditions exist for the solutions:

- Create a temporary file with `GetTempFileName()`, delete it, and create a folder with the same name
- Use `GetRandomFileName()` or `Guid.NewGuid.ToString` to create a random folder name, check whether it exists, and create it if not.

It is possible, however, to create a unique temporary directory atomically by utilizing the [Transactional NTFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363764.aspx) (TxF) API.

TxF has a [`CreateDirectoryTransacted()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363857.aspx) function that can be invoked via Platform Invoke. To do this, I adapted [Mohammad Elsheimy's code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66276/Creating-Transacted-Files-in-Windows-Vista.aspx?display=Print) for calling `CreateFileTransacted()`:

```
// using System.ComponentModel;
// using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// using System.Transactions;

[ComImport]
[Guid("79427a2b-f895-40e0-be79-b57dc82ed231")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IKernelTransaction
{
    void GetHandle(out IntPtr pHandle);
}

// 2.2 Win32 Error Codes <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx>
public const int ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND = 0x3;
public const int ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS = 0xb7;
public const int ERROR_EFS_NOT_ALLOWED_IN_TRANSACTION = 0x1aaf;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool CreateDirectoryTransacted(string lpTemplateDirectory, string lpNewDirectory, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, IntPtr hTransaction);

/// <summary>
/// Creates a uniquely-named directory in the directory named by <paramref name="tempPath"/> and returns the path to it.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tempPath">Path of a directory in which the temporary directory will be created.</param>
/// <returns>The path of the newly-created temporary directory within <paramref name="tempPath"/>.</returns>
public static string GetTempDirectoryName(string tempPath)
{
    string retPath;

    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        IKernelTransaction kernelTransaction = (IKernelTransaction)TransactionInterop.GetDtcTransaction(Transaction.Current);
        IntPtr hTransaction;
        kernelTransaction.GetHandle(out hTransaction);

        while (!CreateDirectoryTransacted(null, retPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, Path.GetRandomFileName()), IntPtr.Zero, hTransaction))
        {
            int lastWin32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            switch (lastWin32Error)
            {
                case ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Win32Exception(lastWin32Error);
            }
        }

        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
    return retPath;
}

/// <summary>
/// Equivalent to <c>GetTempDirectoryName(Path.GetTempPath())</c>.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="GetTempDirectoryName(string)"/>
public static string GetTempDirectoryName()
{
    return GetTempDirectoryName(Path.GetTempPath());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like...

```
using System.IO;

string path = Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetRandomFileName();
while (Directory.Exists(path))
 path = Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetRandomFileName();

Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Comment: maybe with a try-catch to re-enter the loop if you fail to create the directory ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could generate a GUID for your temporary folder names.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the name of the folder doesn't need to be meaningful, how about using a GUID for them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364991(VS.85).aspx) to create a temporary **file**, then delete and re-create this file as a directory instead.

Note: link didn't work, copy/paste from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364991(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Combined answers from @adam-wright and pix0r will work the best IMHO:

```
using System.IO;

string path = Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetRandomFileName();

while (Directory.Exists(path)) 
  path = Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetRandomFileName();

File.Delete(path);
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

The advantage to using System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName is that it will be a file in the user's local (i.e., non-roaming) path. This is exactly where you would want it for permissions and security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim NewFolder = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetTempPath, Guid.NewGuid.ToString))
```

Answer (score 0):

@JonathanWright suggests CreateDirectory will fail when there is already a folder. If I read Directory.CreateDirectory it says 'This object is returned regardless of whether a directory at the specified path already exists.' Meaning you do not detect a folder created between check exists and actually creating.

I like the CreateDirectoryTransacted() suggested by @DanielTrebbien but this function is deprecated.

The only solution I see that is left is to use the c api and call the '[CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx)' there as it does error if the folder exists if you really need to be sure to cover the whole race condition.
That would result in something like this:

```
Private Function GetTempFolder() As String
    Dim folder As String
    Dim succes as Boolean = false
    Do While not succes
        folder = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath, Path.GetRandomFileName)
        success = c_api_create_directory(folder)
    Loop
    Return folder
End Function
```

Comment: A check for looping infinitely would be sensible.